# How can i give ability to user to zoom in and zoom out images on website on mobile device

Tags: jquery, pinchzoom

I am working on website in which they having images of there product and client want images on mobile device have to be zoom in and zoom out on pinch without zooming full site.

Any suggestion how i can achive this ?

Any link to referance ?

Comment: Please provide an code example which shows what you've tried yet.

Comment: I have not tried any code but need some suggestion how many ways i can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this in header of the page

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=2, minimum-scale=0.5, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```